# How to retrieve idAdjustedUTC flag value for a TIMESTAMP column in a parquet file?

Tags: python, timestamp, metadata, parquet, pyarrow

I have a parquet file with a number of columns of type `converted_type (legacy): TIMESTAMP_MICROS`. I want to check if the flag `isAjustedToUTC` is true. I can get it this way:

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import re   
 
arrow = pq.ParquetFile("/Parquet/File/Path/filename.parquet")
timestamp_string = str(arrow.metadata.row_group(0).column(79).statistics.logical_type)
re.search("isAdjustedToUTC=(.*), timeUnit",timestamp_string).group(1)
```

This gives me either `true` or `false` as string. Is there another way to retrieve the value of `isAdjustedToUTC` without using a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's not possible. `logical_type` is of type `pyarrow._parquet.ParquetLogicalType` which doesn't expose directly it's underlying members.

The only available fields are:

```
dir(logical_type)
>> ['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__pyx_vtable__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setstate__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'to_json',
 'type']
```

You could use the `to_json` function, but it's as dirty as the option you've suggested:

```
import json
json.loads(logical_type.to_json())['isAdjustedToUTC']
>> true
```

Comment: Thank you, Arthur. This actually looks better to me.